# Why are verbs like "deny" and "dispute" 'harder to "refute"'?

Tags: difference

I am asking for "lay language", not legalese. I quote [Merrill Perlman](https://journalism.columbia.edu/faculty/merrill-perlman) at [The confusion over ‘rebut’ and ‘refute’](https://www.cjr.org/language_corner/rebut-refute.php). Please see the last sentence of the quotation beneath!  What does "**harder**"  even mean here?  Can someone please paraphrase it?

> [The word you want most of the time is “rebut,” a denial accompanied by argument or presentation of less-than-definitive evidence. If someone claims the sun rises in the west, simply pointing them east at dawn would “refute” that claim.](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/refute-vs-rebut.3906041/#post-19987855) But if someone claims that the Beatles were the greatest rock band the world has ever seen, it is not a provable fact, so any argument to the contrary is a “rebuttal.”
>
> The confusion over “rebut” and “refute” is more than a century old, as we wrote, and though the difference is significant, the needle is starting to move. [Merriam-Webster’s second definition for “refute”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refute) is “to deny the truth or accuracy of,” and its definition of “rebut” includes “to expose the falsity of: refute.” It treats the two words as all but synonyms. *Webster’s New World College Dictionary*, the one preferred by many news organizations, comes close as well:
> It defines “rebut” as “to contradict, refute, or oppose, esp. in a formal manner by argument, proof, etc.,” and its “refute” definition includes “to deny the truth or validity of: usage objected to by some.”
> The “some” includes *The Associated Press*, whose stylebook says “*Rebut* means *to argue to the contrary: He rebutted his opponent’s statement*. Refute connotes success in argument and almost always implies an editorial judgment. Instead, use deny, dispute, rebut or respond to. *The New York Times Manual of Style of Usage* also preserves the distinction. Its “rebut, refute” entry reads: “Rebut, a neutral word, means reply and take issue. Refute goes further, and often beyond what a writer intends: it means disprove, and successfully. Unless that is the intention, use rebut, dispute, deny or reject.
>
> *Garner’s Modern English Usage* also holds the line, not unsurprising, since Bryan A. Garner is a lawyer and the editor of *Black’s Law Dictionary* and *Garner’s Dictionary of Legal Usage*, among other law-related books. He lists the misuse of “refute” for “rebut” and vice versa at Stage 1 on the five-stage Language-Change Index, equivalent to expulsion from a parliamentary body.
>
> Journalists seeking truth and legitimacy should probably avoid “refute” unless there is indisputable evidence that something was inaccurate. **Words like “deny” and “dispute” are harder to “refute.” [embolding mine]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence means that words like "deny" and "dispute" have neutral, descriptive meanings, like "rebut", which makes their usage more difficult to argue against.

This is sort of the whole point of the article, which is why it was included as the final, concluding sentence. The author spends the bulk of the article describing why the word "rebut" should generally be preferred over the word "refute", since the former has only the neutral, descriptive meaning that an objection has been raised, whereas the latter implies that the raised objection was valid, to the point of nullifying/disproving the original assertion.

"Deny" and "dispute" are synonyms of "rebut", whereas "disproven" and "falsify" are synonyms of "refute". In the context of a debate or argument, each participant disputes/rebuts the other participants' arguments. As a neutral observer, you can make this claim without assessing the validity or success of the debaters' arguments. However, if you say that one debater has refuted the other debater's arguments, then you're making a value judgment about the success of their rebuttal, just as if you said that they "won" or "proved" that specific argument.

Because "deny", "dispute", and "rebut" have objective, neutral, descriptive meanings, it is nearly impossible for someone to object to your usage of those words. By contrast, "disprove", "falsify", and "refute" are subject to the opinion/assessment of the individual reader/listener, so these could be easily disagreed with.

**The author is basically saying that if you use "deny", "dispute", and "rebut", since these are neutral terms, then it'll be harder for people to have a valid objection to your word choice (i.e., they won't be able to *refute* your word choice).**

In my opinion as a native English speaker who is quite well-read, including in legal jargon, this is a very confusing sentence. The author was clearly attempting to be clever at the expense of clarity. It took me quite a while to parse the meaning of this final, bolded sentence. Once I figured out what was meant, though, it is quite unambiguous, albeit still difficult for me to explain succinctly and clearly.

Comment: "The author was clearly attempting to be clever at the expense of clarity. "  +1